# Avoiding allocations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization

I'm working on a more complicated program I would like to be very efficient, but I have boiled down my concerns for right now to the following simple program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ foldl (+) 0 [(1::Int)..1000000]
```

Here I build and run it.

```
$ uname -s -r -v -m
Linux 3.12.9-x86_64-linode37 #1 SMP Mon Feb 3 10:01:02 EST 2014 x86_64
$ ghc -V
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
$ ghc -O -prof --make B.hs
$ ./B +RTS -P
500000500000
$ less B.prof
        Sun Feb 16 16:37 2014 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

           B +RTS -P -RTS

        total time  =        0.04 secs   (38 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
        total alloc =  80,049,792 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE  %time %alloc  ticks     bytes

CAF         Main    100.0   99.9     38  80000528


                                                      individual     inherited
COST CENTRE MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc  ticks     bytes

MAIN        MAIN                     44           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0      0     10872
 CAF        Main                     87           0  100.0   99.9   100.0   99.9     38  80000528
 CAF        GHC.IO.Handle.FD         85           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0      0     34672
 CAF        GHC.Conc.Signal          83           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0      0       672
 CAF        GHC.IO.Encoding          76           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0      0      2800
 CAF        GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv    60           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0      0       248
```

It looks like 80 bytes are being allocated per iteration.  I think it's quite reasonable to expect the compiler to generate allocation-free code here.

Is my expectation unreasonable?  Are the allocations a side effect of enabling profiling?  How can I finangle things to get rid of the allocation?

Comment: Use [`foldl'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-). There are good discussions of the differences in various places here on SO and on the Haskell wiki.

Comment: @DanielWagner I get the exact same result with `foldl'`.

Comment: @NovaDenizen I expect you get the same results with `foldl'` due to profiling side-effects.  You can try compiling normally, then running with `+RTS -s`, which produces quite useful information in a minimally-intrusive fashion.  Works for me at any rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it looks like GHC was smart enough to optimize `foldl` into the stricter form, but GHC can't optimize away the intermediate list because `foldl` isn't a [good consumer](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html), so <s>presumably those allocations are for the `(:)` constructors.</s> (**EDIT3**: No, looks like that's not the case; see comments)

By using `foldr` fusion kicks in and you can get rid of the intermediate list:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ foldr (+) 0 [(1::Int)..1000000]
```

...as you can see:

```
       k +RTS -P -RTS

    total time  =        0.01 secs   (10 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc =      45,144 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

which has the same memory profile for me as

```
main = print $ (1784293664 :: Int)
```

**EDIT**: In this new version we're trading heap allocation for a bunch of `(1 + (2 + (3 +...)))` on the stack. To really get a good loop we have to write it by hand like:

```
main = print $ add 1000000

add :: Int -> Int
add nMax = go 0 1 where
    go !acc !n
        | n == nMax = acc + n
        | otherwise = go (acc+n) (n+1)
```

showing:

```
    total time  =        0.00 secs   (0 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc =      45,144 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

**EDIT2** I haven't gotten to use Gabriel Gonzalez [foldl library](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/foldl-100-composable-streaming-and.html) yet, but it also might be worth playing with for your application.

Comment: Are you changing your stacksize?  I get `Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.` now.   I can use `./B +RTS -K24M -P` to get around it, but allocating 24 megs on the stack isn't tremendously better IMO.

Comment: @NovaDenizen it doesn't overflow for me (on GHC 7.6; perhaps the default is higher) but you're absolutely right we're trading heap allocation for a bunch of `(1 + (2 + (3 +...)))` on the stack. Sorry my post was misleading on that point; I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Somewhere in the GHC 7 series, it changed to automatically-growing stacks, which is why it doesn't overflow anymore.

Comment: Oops, I just realized I compiled with 7.8 RC1 which I just installed the other day; it looks like 7.8 but not 7.6 has the dynamically-growing stack stuff. Neat! thanks @Carl

Comment: It's not necessary to write the loop by hand, just use `foldl'`.  `foldl'` isn't a "good consumer" in the list-fusion sense, but it's a good consumer in the tail-recursive sense.  And in this case there's no intermediate list anyway.

Comment: @JohnL ah, you're right about there not being an intermediate list; I should stop guessing. Nevertheless the hand-written version is an order of magnitude faster. Interestingly main allocations are of `ARR_WORDS` (not sure what that signifies in this case), and a heap profile shows the `foldl'` version allocates an N-size block at the beginning while the `add` version grows to `N` as the computation proceeds. Maybe someone else would like to look at the core, etc and really get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @jberryman: the `foldl'` version still has to go through *a* list (produced by a call to `GHC.Enum.eftInt`, whereas the `add` version simply loops over two unboxed ints until it terminates.  I don't consider that an *intermediate* list though, IME most of the time you don't have enough control over the producer to completely remove that structure.